# Expect - Use default variable if no argument is specified

Tags: variables, tcl, expect

I've searched on stackoverflow and haven't really found an answer to this.

I'm pretty new to scripting and I have created a fully functional Expect script but I would like to improve it a bit. Currently I have created 3 lindex values of argv 0, 1 and 2 for hostaddress, username and password.

I would like to create a default username and password if argv 1 and 2 is NOT specified. I tried solving this through some if statements but after searching through stackoverflow it seems that TCL/Expect does not support NULL or empty values. Instead you have to make a query for it. Currently my code looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

#Variables
set HOSTADDRESS [lindex $argv 0]
set USER [lindex $argv 1]
set PASSWORD [lindex $argv 2]

spawn ssh $USER@$HOSTADDRESS

set timeout 100

expect {
        "(yes/no)?" {send "yes\n"; exp_continue}
        "assword:" {send "$PASSWORD\n"}
       }
expect {
        "%" {send "cli\r"; exp_continue}
        ">" {sleep 1}
       }
send "show interfaces st0 terse | match st0. | count \r"
expect "Count:???"
puts [open $HOSTADDRESS.op5.vpn.results w] $expect_out(0,string)
expect ">"
send "exit\r"
expect {
        "%" {send "exit\r"; exp_continue}
        "closed." {exit}
       }
exit
```

Can you guys please help me create a default variable for $USER and $PASSWORD if it's not specified in the argv 1 or argv2?

Answer (score 2):

Tcl doesn't support NULL at all. Or rather, it *actually* maps it to the variable being unset (that's exactly what happens with local variables under the hood; global variables are different). To query whether a variable exists, you use `info exists` (and yes, that's actually a NULL check in its implementation).

However, for handling defaulting of values from users on the command line, it is better to do it like this:

```
proc parseArgv {hostAddress {user "TheDefaultUser"} {pass "TheDefaultPassword"}} {
    variable ::HOSTADDRESS $hostAddress
    variable ::USER $user
    variable ::PASSWORD $pass
}
parseArgv {*}$argv
```

If you're using 8.4 (upgrade, man!) then replace that last line with:

```
eval parseArgv $argv
```

You could also do it by looking at the `llength` of `$argv` (or the value in `$argc`) and doing conditional stuff based on that, but leveraging Tcl's `proc` default argument value stuff is easier (and you even get a reasonable error when someone gives too few or too many arguments).

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I tried adding your lines but I didn't get it to work. The code looks like this now: 'proc parseArgv {hostAddress {user "root"} {pass "password"}} {
    variable ::HOSTADDRESS $hostAddress
    variable ::USER $user
    variable ::PASSWORD $pass
}
parseArgv {*}$argv

spawn ssh $user@$hostAddress
' But I get the following error: 'wrong # args: should be "parseArgv hostAddress ?user? ?pass?"
    while executing
"parseArgv {*}$argv"
    (file "./expect.vpn.check.sh" line 10)
' Is there something that I need to correct?